# Bash vi mode: how to paste from OSX system clipboard

Tags: bash, vi

I'm using `vi` mode in Bash. Currently I can paste from the system clipboard (both in insert and command mode) using `C-v`. When I'm in command mode I would like to paste from the system clipboard with `p`. I tried defining the following bind in my `bash_profile`:

`bind -m vi-command '"p": "run '$(echo pbpaste)'"'`

which is (clearly) wrong. So my question is: how can I paste from the system clipboard using `p` in bash with vi mode.
Can I somehow map `p` to `C-v`?

**Edit:** 

`bind -m vi-command -x '"p": pbpaste'`

will paste the system clipboard before the command prompt. I want to paste it immediately after the cursor.

Comment: If you're on OS X, why not use Command-P (⌘-P)?

Comment: What does `:echo has('clipboard')` return?

Comment: @lan2thedv I believe you refer to vim, I'm asking about vi-mode in bash.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want to paste with `p` as I normally do in vim.

Comment: Not sure, but sounds like you want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366450/complex-keybinding-in-bash) to enter insert mode and then run `pbpaste` with a single keystroke.